# html ajax call can not hit my WebApi method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I can hit this method from POSTMAN but can not hit from simple html page following is the code sample:

Jquery code

```
var certificateNumber = $("#txtCertificateNumber").val();
$("#search-Certificate").click(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8073/api/ami/CertificateDetails",
    data: certificateNumber,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#resultarea").text(data);
    }
  });
});
```

**controller api code**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ami")]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class APIController: ApiController {

   [HttpGet]
   [Route("CertificateDetails/{certificateNumber}")]
   public HttpResponseMessage GetHatcheryCertificateBy(string certificateNumber) {

   }

}
```

Comment: show your `certificateNumber ` value

Comment: Not sure can you use `data: certificateNumber` in ajax GET method